# Последний элемент массива в MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

В базе данных имеются документы следующего вида:

```
{"_id":1,"name":"First","date":[ISODate("2019-02-08T16:30:00Z")]}
{"_id":2,"name":"Second","date":[ISODate("2019-02-08T16:30:00Z"),ISODate("2019-02-08T17:30:00Z")]}
```

Известно, что в массиве date будет храниться либо 1, либо 2 значения.
Подскажите, как получить те документы, в которых ПОСЛЕДНИЙ элемент будет больше определенной даты?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{$or: [ {$and:[{date:{$size:1}}, {'date.0':{$gt: ISODate("2019-01-17T18:03:28.089Z")}} ]}, {$and:[{date:{$size:2}}, {'date.1':{$gt: ISODate("2019-01-17T18:03:28.089Z")}} ]},   ]}
```

Comment: большое спасибо!