# Не выходит переделать запрос из sql в mongoDB

Tags: sql, база-данных, mongodb, запрос

Есть запрос написанный на sql, хочу его переделать для mongoDB, но он почему-то не работает, выдает не то. Что не так?

```
--Вывод расписания в промежутке 
select * from Расписание
where Дата  between '2019-12-30' and '2020-12-31'
order by Дата ASC
go
```

```
db.Расписание.find(  {data : { $gte: "30.12.2019 0:00:00", $lte: "31.12.2019 0:00:00" }}).sort( { data : 1} )
```

[image: Данные в mongo]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Опишите запрос словами, для тех кто не знает sql, Но знает mongodb

Comment: Нужно вывести только те данные у которых в графе "дата" записаны значения входящие в промежуток от 12.30.2019 до 31.12.2020

Comment: у Вас поле `data`, является строкой, поэтому и работать надо как со строкой. Ну и есстественно, такое сравнение как у Вас в запросе не подходит. Если же Вы измените поле на тип Date, тогда, в Вашем запросе, дату оберните  вот так `ISODate("2019-01-17T18:03:28.089Z")`, и по идее, все заработает. Вот тут можете посмотреть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/933371/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2-mongodb/933433#933433